# ModuleNotFoundError: I can't import custom modules properly

Tags: python, module

below the folder structure of my software:

[image]

below the code of all the .py files:

run.py:

```
import modules.module_01.aa as a

a.test()

# test:
if __name__=="__main__":
    pass
```

aa.py (module 1):

```
import libraries.qq as q
import libraries.zz as z

def test():
    q.qq_fun()
    z.zz_fun()
    print("ciao")
```

qq.py (library used by aa.py):

```
def qq_fun():
    pass
```

zz.py (library used by aa.py):

```
def zz_fun():
    pass
```

my question is really simple, why when I run "run.py" Python say to me:

[image]

why "aa.py" can't import the module "qq.py" and "zz.py"? how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## run.py

In `run.py`, the Python interpreter thinks you're trying to import `module_01.aa` from a module named `module`. To import `aa.py`, you'll need to add this code to the top of your file, which adds the directory `aa.py` is in to the system path, and change your import statement to `import aa as a`.

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, "./modules/module_01/")
```

## aa.py

The same problem occurs in `aa.py`. To fix the problem in this file, you'll need to add this code to the top of `aa.py`, which adds the directory `qq.py` and `zz.py` are in, and remove the `libraries.` from both of your import statements.

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, "./modules/module_01/libraries")
```